# How to handle managed exception in unmanaged code

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, com, unmanaged, managed

I have C++ project which is COM based, in which am accessing the C# assembly. I want to write the code to handle the exception in com project which are thrown by C# assembly.

I tried by placing the try and catch blocks, but exceptions are not been thrown instead the HRESULT value is less than zero. I need the exact message string to display which is thrown by C# API.

Please provide the guidelines for this.

Comment: If all you want is to know the error message, you could keep the last exception message in a variable then expose it with GetLastErrorMsg() method. Call that method when you get HRESULT value less than zero.

Comment: I don't think you can access managed information (the exception string) from the unmanaged world. Check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/liviuc/archive/2009/10/13/.net-interop-and-exception-handling-in-mixed-applications.aspx . It says: "...you will not be able to get managed exception information in a native handler - you must use try/catch in C++/CLI - that is, in a managed context - if you really need that information.". You can catch it though.

Comment: I didn't find the GetLastErrorMsg()... I can see GetLastError() which returns DWORD.

Answer (score 1):

You have two sources of info available.  First off, the HRESULT that is returned is not arbitrary, every managed exception has a [distinctive HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that helps you identify the kind of Exception object that was thrown.

Next, the CLR implements the [IErrorInfo interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can QI on the interface pointer you used to call the managed method to get the IErrorInfo interface pointer.  IErrorInfo::GetDescription() returns the Exception.Message property value.

That's where it ends, no way to get the holy stack trace.